# Concatenate removes comma from list, why?

Tags: python-3.x, list

After concatenating of 2 lists the commas are gone. But for columnar I need the commas.
How to get them back ?

```
data list: [['bc1qxerefpfv3eaje77pmz44uuhkrtuss96pr8l86h', '0.01001904'], ['bc1qqd3v30aq6fsjnyl236rft7607rcdj4sjj3f4ty', '0.00476636']]
receiver list: [['36P29dTs6XnAiVxiMxZqmKBm1bFpsHfueR', '0.00167392'],['3D38TeCNgMdJBScz5CXnKkuKSUZpU7Y4mH',         '0.01011148']] 

import numpy as np
result=np.concatenate((data,receiver),axis=1)
```

```
result:[['bc1qxerefpfv3eaje77pmz44uuhkrtuss96pr8l86h' '0.01001904'
  '36P29dTs6XnAiVxiMxZqmKBm1bFpsHfueR' '0.00167392']
 ['bc1qqd3v30aq6fsjnyl236rft7607rcdj4sjj3f4ty' '0.00476636'
  '3D38TeCNgMdJBScz5CXnKkuKSUZpU7Y4mH' '0.01011148']]
```

2 Lists:

[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,5]]
[[23,56][78,89]]

output should be:

1  2  23  56
3  4  78  89
5  6
7  8
9  5

```
result = list(map(list.__add__, list1, list2))
doesn't work
```

Comment: You're concatenating using numpy function so the result is a numpy array (which doesn't include commas in its representation). In order to concatenate two lists you can just sum them: `result = data + receiver` will return a list with all elements of `data` and `receiver`

Comment: Thanks, but I need first record from the first list, then first record of the second list and so on....

Comment: You should edit your question with the desired output. `zip` might be useful but without further info it's hard to tell

Comment: I looked into zip, which works fine, except if amount of data differs. I need one dataset from the first list, then the first dataset of the second list, then the second dataset of the first list, then the second dataset of the second list...... But if there is no dataset in one of the list anymore, it should move on with zipping but just adding empty dataset......(add dataset from first list, add empty dataset from second list (if there is no dataset in the second list))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last edit, it seems that you could use `itertools.zip_longest`. Use a triple loop and set your brackets right to get the desired structure:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

data = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,5]]
receiver = [[23,56],[78,89]]

result = [[x for l in tup for x in l] for tup in zip_longest(data, receiver, fillvalue=[])]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 23, 56], [3, 4, 78, 89], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now with: print(tabulate(result, headers=["Sender","Value", "Receiver", "Value"])), but not with columnar, but I'm happy with that. For columnar I would need like Spaces or "-" for an empty dataset. Maybe I'll work it out.  [[1, 2, 23, 56], [3, 4, 78, 89], [5, 6, '-','-'], [7, 8,'-','-'], [9, 5, '-','-']]

Comment: Simply specify `fillvalue=["-", "-"]` in `zip_longest` to make it work with columnar.

Comment: Oh my god, you are a genius, it works! :)